# EditorJS. Telegram and TikTok embed does not working

Tags: javascript, iframe, editorjs

Is there a way to insert embed from telegram or tiktok by straight url?

Right now my code looks like

```
function insertEmbed(service, link) {
    let embed = link

    if (service === "youtube") {
        const id = new URLSearchParams(new URL(link).search).get("v")
        embed = `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${id}`
    } else if (service === "instagram") {
        link = link.split("?").shift()
        embed = `${link}${link.endsWith("/") ? "embed" : "/embed"}`
    } else if (service === "twitter") {
        embed = `https://twitframe.com/show?url=${encodeURIComponent(link)}`
    }

    editor.blocks.insert("embed", {
        service: service,
        source: link,
        embed: embed,
    }, null, embedBlockId.value === -1 ? null : embedBlockId.value, true)

    embedBlock.value?.classList.remove("active")
}
```

Because Embed doesn't have telegram and tiktok as internal services, documentation suggest to [write them](https://github.com/editor-js/embed?tab=readme-ov-file#add-more-services) by your own

So, in config I have that:

```
embed: {
    class: Embed,
    inlineToolbar: true,
    config: {
        services: {
            youtube: true,
            twitter: true,
            instagram: true,
            telegram: {
                regex: /https?:\/\/t\.me\/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\/(\d+)/,
                embedUrl: "https://t.me/<%= remote_id %>",
                html: `<script async src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?4" data-telegram-post="durov/45" data-width="100%"></script>`,
                height: 600,
                width: 800,
            },
        }
    },
},
```

But in Editor block I don't get iframe block with post or something, only caption

Is there any libs, plugins or anything else?
Maybe I missing something?